# Heap out of memory, all retained memory held by noscript_shared_function_infos

Tags: c++, memory, v8, embedded-v8

My application creates a lot of functions with callbacks, this is done in the following way:

```
v8::Local<v8::Function> myFunc = v8::Function::New(
      i->GetCurrentContext(),
      FunctionInvokerCallback(),
      this->WrapDelegate(callbackInvoke),
      0,
      v8::ConstructorBehavior::kThrow,
      v8::SideEffectType::kHasSideEffect).ToLocalChecked();

//persistentObject is a weak Global reference with a callback to clean up native resources
this->objectHandle->persistentObject->Get(i)->Set(i->GetCurrentContext(), functionName, myFunc).FromJust();
```

The memory grows and eventually there is an OOM error and a crash. Upon looking at the heap snapshot, I find that most of the retained memory is held by noscript_shared_function_infos in (strong roots).

My guess is either the sharedFunctionInfos aren't cleaned up (and grow and grow and grow), or worse my actual functions aren't cleaned up (when no longer in use).

How do I delete the infos / or the actual functions after I'm done?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `while(!V8::IdleNotification()) {};`?
Shouldn't `noscript_shared_function_infos` be handled by v8's GC?

I have same issue but with Script::Run in new context. Seems like every time it invoked with script that has `function ...() {}` it appends some bytes to `noscript_shared_function_infos` WeakRef Array then never clean it.

I've found only some questions on different platforms (like [that](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/28988)) and zero answers from someone who knows v8 well. It's sad.